# why net-snmp 5.5-57 is not accepting special characters (&,^,$) for encryption key and authentication key.

Tags: net-snmp

net-snmp version 5.5.57
centos-6.4

i am including following special characters($,&,^) as part of my encryption key and authentication key for SNMPv3 user. But it failed to perform SNMP operations like GET/SET....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about version 5.5.57, but version 5.7.2 works:

```
% snmpget --version
NET-SNMP version: 5.7.2

% snmpget -v 3 -u user7 -l authPriv -a sha -A '1234567890abcde&^$f' -x AES -X '1&^$234567890abcdef' 10.48.0.1 sysDescr.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software ..IOS (tm) RSP Software (RSP-JSV56I-M), Version 12.1(7), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)..Copyright (c) 1986-2001 by cisco Systems, Inc...Compiled Fri 23-Feb-01 05:14 by kellythw
```

and it took 5 minutes to verify with our simulator.